# In spark.read.format('jdbc') how to use NOLOCK when reading from MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark

I couldn't find an option to set `NOLOCK` while reading a table from SQL Server using Spark. How  do it?

Here is my code to read a table from SQL Server:

```py
df = (spark.read.format('jdbc')
    .option('url',str_con)
    .option('driver',driver)
    .option('fetchsize',fetchsize)
    .option('dbtable',source_table_name) # here is the table name
    .option('user',usu_login)
    .option('password',usu_senha)
    .option('schema', get_schema(columns))
    .load()
)
```

I'm using Spark 2.4 and the default jdbc connector.

Comment: Don't. Just don't. It's not the automatic "go faster" switch you've been led to believe.

Comment: Why would you want to use that ? Is there any reason for using it ? What do you think it does

Comment: `READ_UNCOMMITED` (and `NOLOCK` hints) can result in duplicated or missing rows from query results and therefore [should not be used in production code](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206485/best-situation-to-use-read-uncommitted-isolation-level).

Comment: I'm copying data for my data lake where some data analysis will be made. There is no problem if a couple of dirty registers come into. The data ingestion is during an off use period. Using it will prevent the ingestion process to lock my tables and degrade performance.